# JSON Schema validation in .NET [ when JArray object is the input for API Controller verb actions ]

Tags: .net, json, api, validation

I'm developing an API for our project, whose controller methods will take JArray object as parameter for input data. In this case, I've used JSON schema validation, which works apt for validating the data using generated schema. Later, came to know that, to proceed further with JSON schema validation I've to buy license.Before buying, I just want to confirm that JSON schema is the only solution in my case or are there any other validation methods. Valuable suggestions are appreciated.

TIA